# Ruby notification daemon with RabbitMQ and APNS

Tags: ruby, push-notification, daemon, rabbitmq, apple-push-notifications

I want to create a Ruby notification daemon which grab a notification job from RabbitMQ and send that notification to APNS, 
The message for notification jobs will be in the following JSON format: { device_token: [ token1, token2, ...], message: "Hello World!!" }
i have created a daemon with daemon-kit

is there any good tutorial for this? i googled but didnt find luck, i found a [ruby-apns-daemon](http://code.google.com/p/ruby-apns-daemon/) , but it was showing errors